# Unable to add/attach screenshot and test steps in Report

Tags: test-automation-framework, javascript, protractor, jasmine

I am working on protractor and using "protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter" to generate the report. But I am unable to add screenshot and test steps in this report. Can anyone please help me with this. Any help from anyone is appreciated. Below I have attached the report that I am getting. I want to add some steps like "Clicked on web Element name" after clicking on any web Element:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post your protractor config and also highlight where the "Clicked on web Element name" would come from? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, @alecxe it will not come from my config file, like right now i am using console.log(text) to print some action like after using getText(),then it is printing in the console window,but my requirement is to print it in the report.I just want to customise this report....My method is--- textMsg.getText().then(function (text) {
  
    console.log(text);
   
  });

Comment: Right, understood this part. I would still like to see your Protractor config - the way you've configured the reporter. Thanks.

Comment: Nono, please edit your question and include it there. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe i have added my config file